# can you append 2 numpy arrays such that they are nested?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is there a way to append one numpy array to another so that the original array becomes a nested array, instead of the 2 arrays merging together as one?

Consider the following:

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
arr3 = np.append(arr, arr2)
print(arr3)
```

The output would be something like:

```
array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
```

Is there a way to join these 2 arrays together to give:

```
array([1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
```

instead?

Comment: You want `np.vstack((arr1,arr2))`

Comment: use `stack()` method **i.e** `np.stack((arr,arr2),axis=0)`

Comment: Though that doesn't *nest* arrays (not that it would make sense), it makes a two-dimensional array. A chessboard is not nested either.

Comment: Don't use `np.append` - or at least read its docs carefully.

Comment: seems like `list([arr.tolist(), arr2.tolist()])` is what is being asked for, or even `arr3 =[arr.tolist(), arr2.tolist()]`

Answer (score 1):

```
In [7]: arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
   ...: arr2 = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
```

take a clue from the `np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])` construction:

```
In [8]: np.array([arr,arr2])
Out[8]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

`np.vstack` and `np.stack` also work.  They tweak the array dimensions and end up using `np.concatenate`.

`np.append` also uses `np.concatenate`, but does not tweak the dimensions in a way that you want.  If you spent time reading its docs, you'll see that without `axis` it flattens the inputs.

```
In [10]: np.append(arr, arr2)
Out[10]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
In [11]: np.append(arr, arr2,axis=0)
Out[11]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
In [12]: np.append(arr, arr2,axis=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-12-a03796c6f87f>", line 1, in <module>
    np.append(arr, arr2,axis=1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in append
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4745, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in concatenate
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

`np.append` has an example of how to correctly make a multirow array:

```
>>> np.append([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9]], axis=0)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Sooner or latter you need to read enough of the `numpy` basics to understand array shapes.